# Converting razor pages to angular 6 view

Tags: asp.net, angular6, razor-pages

I have a huge asp.net project, my aim is to replace all the razor pages with angular 6 views ,if this is possible, How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are not any existing rules for converting MVC view template to Angular.

To achieve your requirement: implement CRUD functionality with Angular, you could create services to implement these features, and then you can import and use your services in your Angular classes or components.

Besides, for data/input validation, you can use client-side form validation to achieve it.

For more information about Angular, please check [Getting started with Angular](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart).